# Lining up strings with list object lengths

Tags: python-3.x

I've got this function that compares stats that I pull from a txt file, so they are static. I was trying to think of a way to line up the stats of each race/subrace with the names. Here's the source :

```
def compare():
    print('------ Compare Race Stats ------')
    comp1 = query()
    comp2 = query()
    comp1 = stats(comp1[0],comp1[1])
    comp2 = stats(comp2[0],comp2[1])
    print('{} - {} | {} - {}'
          .format(comp1[0][0],comp1[0][1],comp2[0][0],comp2[0][1]))
    for i in range(len(comp1[1])):
        print('{}{}{}{}'.format(' '*round(len(comp1[0][0])+len(comp1[0][1])/5),comp1[1][i],
                                ' '*round(len(comp2[0][0])+2+len(comp2[0][1])/5),comp2[1][i]))
```

`query()` asks what race/subrace you want and returns strings for each. `stats()` takes race/subrace names, pulls from txt file and returns stats along with the names. The `+2` in the second empty space calculation is my accounting for the first print statement (`print('{} - {} | {} - {}'`), that was a guess. The output doesn't look so bad and I thought the space calculation was kind of clever(I'm a noob) but I couldn't help but wonder what Stack Overflow would have to say. Are there certain accepted ways of lining up various outputs.

Here's some output, there are 10 different race/subraces:

```
Elezen - Duskwight | Hyur - Midlander
        STR : 20        STR : 21
        DEX : 20        DEX : 19
        VIT : 19        VIT : 20
        INT : 23        INT : 21
        MND : 20        MND : 18
        PIE : 18        PIE : 21

Mi'Qote - Seekers of the Sun | Mi'Qote - Keepers of the Moon
           STR : 21             STR : 18
           DEX : 22             DEX : 21
           VIT : 20             VIT : 17
           INT : 18             INT : 19
           MND : 19             MND : 23
           PIE : 20             PIE : 22
```

Answer (score 0):

After a little research I found the `rjust` and `ljust` `str` functions:

```
def compare():
    print("------ Compare Race Stats ------")
    comp1 = query()
    comp2 = query()
    comp1 = stats(comp1[0], comp1[1])
    comp2 = stats(comp2[0], comp2[1])
    print("{} - {} | {} - {}"
          .format(comp1[0][0], comp1[0][1], comp2[0][0], comp2[0][1]))
    for i in range(len(comp1[1])):
        print("{} {} {}".format(comp1[1][i].rjust(len(comp1[0][0]+comp1[0][1])+3),
                                "|", comp2[1][i]))
```

Here's the output:

```
Roegadyn - Hellsguard | Elezen - Duskwight
             STR : 20 | STR : 20
             DEX : 17 | DEX : 20
             VIT : 21 | VIT : 19
             INT : 20 | INT : 23
             MND : 22 | MND : 20
             PIE : 20 | PIE : 18

Mi'Qote - Keepers of the Moon | Roegadyn - Hellsguard
                     STR : 18 | STR : 20
                     DEX : 21 | DEX : 17
                     VIT : 17 | VIT : 21
                     INT : 19 | INT : 20
                     MND : 23 | MND : 22
                     PIE : 22 | PIE : 20
```

My apologies for asking a question I should have answered myself before posting, the least I can do it give an answer obviously.